# Searching a table with less rows compared with searching a table with more rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

First off, I would have to say that this might not be one of my brightest questions. Okay. My question is, is there a significant amount of delay from searching a table with less rows compare to searching a table with more rows? And if so, is there anything we can do to reduce the time needed to search a larger table? Sorry, I know. A really vague question. Any information would be great though.

**Table with 1,000 rows**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName = '1';
```

**Table with 1,000,000 rows**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName = '1';
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve? You would get a more helpful answer if you could provide more specific information

Comment: index the columns being searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fetching more rows will take more memory, either a trivial amount or not.
2. The time difference to fetch may be trivial or not.
3. Whether your table has 1,000 or 1,000,000 rows, you may often need only a small batch at a time (50 at a time, 100 at a time, etc.).
4. If the table is indexed (which most are), the difference is exponentially less than if not, when we're talking about large numbers of records.
5. It also depends on what you're doing with the records: counting them, writing them to output, etc.
6. When in doubt,run timed tests and analyze the results.

P.S. The only truly dumb question is the one not asked.